# Combine: cancel a flat-mapped Timer.publisher

Tags: swift, timer, combine

suppose I have

```
let stream = PassthroughSubject<String?, Never>()
let repeated = stream.flatMap { value in Timer.publish(every: 3, on: .main, in: .default).autoconnect() }
```

What I want to achieve is to use the `Timer.publish` function to make a certain operation every 3 seconds **if** `value != nil`, and to stop doing it when `stream` emits nil.

The first part is easily achieved, how to I kill the flat mapped publisher once the subject emits nil?

Comment: What if the String is empty?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to map and then switchToLatest... Like this:

```
let stream = PassthroughSubject<String?, Never>()
let repeated = stream.map { value in
    value == nil
    ? Empty().eraseToAnyPublisher()
    : Timer.publish(every: 3, on: .main, in: .default).autoconnect().eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
    .switchToLatest()
```